# Access, VBA & browser control: switch focus

Tags: vba, ms-access

my Access & VBA application opens a IE browser to manage a website (fill text, etc). After this operation, the active state is obviously focused on the IE windows. At this point, I have to return the state active on the access windows. I have tried some solutions (DoCmd... etc) but nothing works. How can I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: You are using the Access WebBrowser control? Or are you opening independent IE browser?

Comment: Thank for the answer and sorry for the delay! I use the code of this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44341442/access-vba-web-page-complex-control?noredirect=1#comment75686168_44341442 thank you very much, let me know.

Comment: So you are opening an independent IE browser window which has focus and you want to return to Access? I really don't know any way to do that.